# Is it a common approach to use MARS in case of a multiple linear regression in which heteroscedasticity exists?

Tags: regression, linear, mars

I have performed a multiple linear regression with R and there is heteroscedasticity in the data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Crh5XPwxTeWWRyWDFCU0FMbXM/view

Even if I log transform the dependent variable:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Crh5XPwxTeQWVXcFRMaVh4SjQ/view

Is it possible to just apply MARS as a non-linear method or do I have to take anything into account before using MARS? Is there any other method I could apply to my data?